# Get fields from a form in htmlagilitypack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I want to get the data for a form so i wrote the below. It didnt work

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@name='F1']//input[@name]");
```

Breaking it up into two steps did

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@name='F1']");
var nodes = node.SelectNodes("//input[@name]");
```

However i get the data from the entire html file rather then the node/form which is unexpected. How do i get the results from that form only? I tried `/input[@name]` and `.//input[@name]` which gave me null

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is default behavior for `<form>` tag parsing in Html Agility Pack. As they said [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/21782):

> FORM is treated
>   like this because many HTML pages used to have overlapping forms, as
>   this was actually a (powerful) feature of original HTML. Now that XML
>   and XHTML exist, everybody assumes that overlapping is an error, but
>   it's not (in HTML 3.2).

You could change it by using:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
```

and your `"//form[@name='F1']//input[@name]"` expression should work. Or change the second expression to `".//input[@name]"` and it also should work:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@name='F1']");
var nodes = node.SelectNodes(".//input[@name]");
```