# HTML Parse and retrieve value from tags

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse the below HTML:

```
<area name="Footer" parentName="currentDraw">
   <line x1=12 y1=5 x2=600 y2=5 penWidth=2>
   <o y=5><center>ΤΥΠΩΘΗΚΕ 28/07/2020 10:36:25</center></o>
   <center>ΠΡΑΚΤΟΡΕΙΟ: 234022-234022002 23402282</center>
   <center>ΚΩΔ. ΣΥΝ.:cb3fba</center>
   <center>ΚΩΔ. ΔΕΛΤΙΟΥ.:100003627571</center>
   <center><barcode format=graphics type=PDF value="292357408800000058881443144488010000008723000000974152808"></barcode></center>
 </area>
```

using the HtmlAgilityPack. I was able to retrive the node area using the

```
Dim strname As HtmlNode
strname = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//area[@name='Footer']")
```

Now I would like to retrieve the value of the **5 center** but I can't find the way to retrieve it.

I need to have the below value:

```
ΤΥΠΩΘΗΚΕ 28/07/2020 10:36:25 
ΠΡΑΚΤΟΡΕΙΟ: 234022-234022002 23402282 
ΚΩΔ. ΣΥΝ.:cb3fba 
ΚΩΔ. ΔΕΛΤΙΟΥ.:100003627571
292357408800000058881443144488010000008723000000974152808
```

in 5 different variables or in an object.

If I run strname.ChildNodes.Count() the result is 0.

The picture below shows what I need to obtain:

[image]

Comment: So, you want the y value from the o element?

Comment: i need to have the below value : ΤΥΠΩΘΗΚΕ 28/07/2020 10:36:25 --- ΠΡΑΚΤΟΡΕΙΟ: 234022-234022002 23402282 ---- ΚΩΔ. ΣΥΝ.:cb3fba ---- ΚΩΔ. ΔΕΛΤΙΟΥ.:100003627571 ---- 292357408800000058881443144488010000008723000000974152808 in 5 different variable or in on object

Comment: Oh, you mean you're looking for innerHTML of the center elements and the barcode's value which is also wrapped inside <center> tags?

Comment: yes correct i need that value

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to parse HTML with the AgilityPack but you should be able to parse each "center node" in strname.  You'll need to check for a barcode child element to grab that value if it exists in that loop.

Comment: Fossi in te userei Xml.XmlDocument per poi navigare sui nodi estrapolando gli elementi e prendendo gli attributi Xml.XmlAttribute

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540794/10633285 XML != HTML which is what OP said this was and based on the <center> tag it's heavily inferred.

Comment: @LucaRuggeri `Dim centers = strname.SelectNodes("//center")` (strname is a poor variable name), and then you will have to deal with one of the `<center>` nodes having a child node.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : i was able to use             objNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//center")    my question now is 
why
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//area[@name='Footer']//center")
does not works ?
         
         
         debugLogJsonFormat(objNodes.Count())
         debugLogJsonFormat(objNodes2.Count())

Comment: @Luca If you rename "area" to something else, for example "qqq", it will work iwth, e.g. `Dim centers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//qqq[@name='Footer']//center")`. It *might* be related to the problem with "form" in [Get fields from a form in htmlagilitypack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191273/get-fields-from-a-form-in-htmlagilitypack), but using `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("area")` didn't work for me.